# TFS API using c#

Tags: c#, tfs

I have find all collection from TFS all are fine. but i am not Understand why get username and password in  windows security essential dialog to  save TFS username and Password and URL . Please share to me . 
This is one main problem in client machine.

Sample code

```
Uri configurationServerUri = new Uri("http://your-server:8080/tfs");
TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(configurationServerUri);
ITeamProjectCollectionService tpcService = configurationServer.GetService<ITeamProjectCollectionService>();
foreach (TeamProjectCollection tpc in tpcService.GetCollections())
{
   List.add(tpc .name);
}
```

[windows screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwiYH.png)

[image]

Comment: There's credential properties on the configuration server object, have you tried setting those? When I set it using this code I managed to get the list of collections: `config.ClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential(@"DOMAIN ADMIN", "PASSWORD")));` I had to pick a user that had administrative rights on the TFS server in question.

Comment: If you have enough rights you can try this: `configurationServer.ClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [TfsConfigurationServer Constructor (Uri, ICredentials)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732861(v=vs.120).aspx) instead of `TfsConfigurationServer Constructor (Uri)`, then you can specify the credentials that are used to authenticate the user to the server, as @Lasse V. Karlsen mentioned in comment.